# Printing content from a url in javascript via iframe

Tags: javascript, iframe

There's heaps of solutions for this on SO, i tried most of them but unfortunately no luck..

My code:

```
<iframe id="printWindow" name="printWindow" height="0" width="0"></iframe>
```

```
printOrder() {
  const iframeElement: HTMLIFrameElement = document.getElementById('printWindow') as HTMLIFrameElement;
  if(typeof iframeElement === 'undefined') {
    this.errorMessage = 'Could not print order! Iframe not found.';
    return;
  }

  // Setting the print url on the iframe src
  iframeElement.setAttribute('src', this.printUrl);

  // Reload the print window to fetch new src
  iframeElement.contentWindow.location.reload();

  // Focussing the window and printing
  setTimeout(function() {
    iframeElement.contentWindow.focus();
    iframeElement.contentWindow.print();
  }, 300);
}
```

What happens (in Chrome) is that the `printOrder()` function downloads a PDF with the correct page content from `this.printUrl`.

It also opens up a print window, however it does not display the correct page content inside of the print window. It shows a 'blank page' instead.

The variable `this.printUrl` has to be dynamically generated, that is why I set it on the src via script.

Comment: How do you open the "print wndow"?

Comment: calling `focus()` + `print()` should be enough

Comment: Have you tried https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLIFrameElement/contentDocument ?